# Remove object from photo using Expo (React native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, image-editor

I want to implement photo editor functionality (Remove object from photo).

I spent so much time finding NPM and library but didn't found any library which is compatible with the expo to remove objects from photos.

[image]

Remove Object form Image
[image]

I appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

Thanks